# Trying to call Django view on button submit and redirect to the same page (reloaded)

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to call a view that registers players to a tournament on button click, register them in the view, then essentially refresh the page to reflect their new registration. I have here views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Tournament, TournamentRegistration


def index(request):
    tournaments = Tournament.objects.order_by("-start_time")
    context = {'tournaments': tournaments}
    return render(request, 'tournaments/index.html', context)


def tournament_detail(request, tourney_id):
    tournament = Tournament.objects.get(pk=tourney_id)
    user = request.user
    player_is_registered = TournamentRegistration.player_is_registered(tourney_id, user.id)
    print(player_is_registered)
    if player_is_registered:
        registered = 'yes'
    else:
        registered = 'no'
    context = {'tournament': tournament, 'player_is_registered': registered}
    return render(request, 'tournaments/tournament_detail.html', context)


def register_for_tournament(request, tourney_id, player_id):
    registration = TournamentRegistration(tournament=tourney_id, player=player_id)
    registration.save()
    return redirect(tournament_detail, tourney_id=tourney_id)
```

tournaments/urls.py:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<tourney_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.tournament_detail, name='tournament_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<tourney_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<player_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.register_for_tournament, name='tournament_registration'),
]
```

main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^tournaments/', include('tournaments.urls')),
    url(r'', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),

]
```

The template for tournament registration:

```
  <body>
    <p>User ID: {{ user.id }}</p>
    <p>{{ tournament.name }}</p>
    <p>Start time: {{ tournament.start_time }}</p>
    <p>Registered: {{ player_is_registered }}</p>

    <form action="/tournaments/{{tournament.pk}}/{{user.id}}" method="GET">
      <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>

  </body>
```

I came up with this code based on examples I found online. But to my dismay, instead of refreshing and showing the same page with the player registered, it takes the browser to the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tournaments/1/1?` which is being caught as the "home" page (the url page with name 'home' in the main urls file).

I checked the tournament detail page again to see if it registered the player, and it did not. So neither of my goals is being met. What am I doing wrong in trying to call this view from a button and redirect to the same page with the new info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is two fold. Firstly, you didn't add a slash at the end of your action URL:

```
<form action="/tournaments/{{tournament.pk}}/{{user.id}}/" ..
```

Although really you should have used the `url` tag here, which would have correctly output the whole URL including the slash:

```
<form action="{% url 'tournament_registration' tournament.pk user.id %}" ...
```

And secondly you didn't anchor the home URL, so it matches everything that doesn't match anything else. It should be:

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
```